# Authentication using socket.io and a .NET server?

Tags: .net, cordova, socket.io

I'm trying to create a simple cordova application that allows users to sign up and then receive messages broadcast from the server.

I'm still relatively new to cordova and I'm having a hard time understanding how the communication will work between the mobile device and the server.

In the past I've created a dummy application that allowed my angular apps to authenticate with a .Net server, using the following: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

This worked great for allowing my angular apps to authenticate but now I'm trying to create a mobile client, I'm confused about how this will work.

In my mind I picture the client signing up and logging in via the above approach. But when it comes to sending/receiving messages, I figured I should be using web sockets/socket.io to communicate - but at this point I'm confused about how the authentication would work.

Could anyone at least point me in the right direction here? I suppose my main questions are:

How should cordova apps be communicating with the server? Should the client be making web requests or should I be using communicating using socket.io. If the latter, then how do I go about authentication?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just coming back to give an update: I basically abandoned using socket.io since Microsoft pretty much has it's own equivalent with SignalR - obviously it integrates nicely with .Net!